# Time shift in differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, perturbation-theory

It is about singular pertubation theory.

I found the following article: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9399/c56a5f407d3b1037db131d17f00144ee49ba.pdf

When looking at eq. $(7)$ shouldn't there be also a part $\frac{d \varphi}{d \tau}$ after $g(\cdot)$? Why do they only replace $\epsilon \frac{d y}{d t} = \frac{d y}{d \tau}$?

As reqested, here more context (in case that the link breaks down):

The following dynamic system is considered
$$\dot{x}=f(x,z,u,t,\epsilon)$$
$$\epsilon \dot{z}=g(x,z,u,t,\epsilon)$$

In singular pertubation model, the model order is reduced by neglecting the fast dynamics, hence, $\epsilon = 0$ leading to $0=g(\bar{x},\bar{z},\bar{u},t,0)$. The roots of this equation are then calculated as follows:
$$\bar{z}=\varphi(\bar{x},\bar{u},t)$$
The system from above is then converted into the reduced model
$$\dot{\bar{x}}=f(\bar{x},\varphi(\bar{x},\bar{u},t),\bar{u},t,0)$$

Now we transform the system in the following way:
$$y=z-\varphi(\bar{x},\bar{u},t)$$

where $\epsilon \frac{d y}{d t} = \frac{d y}{d \tau}$ is used to get the following result:
$$\frac{dy}{d \tau}=g(t,x,y+\varphi(t,x),0)$$
The last equation is eq. (7).

Comment: A question should be self-contained, namely links can break. So could you add equation $(7)$ to your question?